# Chern classes : Topological vs algebraic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$. Then in literature one finds that : considering $X$ as a topological space and $E$ to be a complex vector bundle on it, one defines the topological Chern class $c_s(E)\in H^{2s}(X, \mathbb Z)$.

On the other hand we can also define its Chern class $c_s(E)\in A^{s}(X)$, where $A^{s}(X)$ stands for codimension $s$ cycles on $X$.

Then my question are the following:

$(i)$ Can we use smoothness of $X$ to deduce that $H^{2s}(X, \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z$? for example can we say something like $H^4(X, \mathbb Z) \cong \mathbb Z$? (In our particular case)

Is there a formula for $H^{t}(X, \mathbb Z)$, depending on whether $t$ is even or odd?

$(ii)$ Is there way to relate these two definitions : $A^s(X)$ and $H^{2s}(X, \mathbb Z)$?

Any argument from anyone is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your $X$ is a complex variety, I don't know if any of this even makes any sense in finite characteristic.

In general, if $M$ is a orientable compact manifold of dimension $d$, you have
$$H^d(M, \mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z,$$
so in your case $d = 4$ your point (i) holds. <s>Iirc, on a complex manifold you have $H^t(X, \mathbb Z) = 0$ for $t$ odd. For even $t$, there is no such formula easy.</s> I was mistaken. As Michael Albanese pointed out in the comments, [tori have odd cohomology groups.](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/the-cohomology-of-the-n-torus/) As $H^k(M, \mathbb Z)$ is a topological invariant, this does not depend at all on the complex structure...

For (ii), there is a homomorphism $A^s(X) \to H^{2s}(X, \mathbb Z)$, which maps the algebraic Chern classes to the topological ones. See Fulton's *Intersection Theory* for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So basically a smooth projective surface over complex number is interpreted as a complex manifold of dimension $4$ and then the one uses the homomorphism and then the isomrphism fact.Is the isomrphism there in Fultons book? Does $H^k(X,Z)$ only makes sense in the topological/ manifold setting? Could you suggest some reference where I can learn about this cohomology groups?

Comment: @Sherlock Note that as complex manifold, the (complex) dimension is still 2, but the real dimension is 4. For compact (eg projective) varieties, you can take singular cohomology. This is for example treated in Hatcher's *Algebraic topology* or Dold's *Lectures on Algebraic Topology*. Fulton writes that for general varieties, you take Borel-Moore homology, which I'm not really familiar with. But according to Wikipedia, this is the same as singular homology, on compact spaces.

Comment: The statement about odd degree cohomology is incorrect (consider tori).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Right, thank you! Don't know why I thought this to be true...